# What is the time reference for GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime()?

Tags: c#, windows

Using the following code is supposed to return the current time, but instead is returning a wrong time like "131956027702298694".

The relevant code is:

```
long filetime;
GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(out filetime);
```

And to import the method:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
private static extern void GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(out long filetime);
```

Any clue on what could be wrong?

EDIT:
As Jarrod and Hans pointed out I missed the part where it states the reference time. For some reason I expected it to be the usual epoch time reference. So it is indeed returning the correct time, just not how I naively expected.

Comment: What part of the documentation for that function that states [*"Contains a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC)."*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime) is unclear?

Comment: That's February 25th, 2019, pretty current.  Easy to see when you use DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc().

Answer (score 1):

```
long filetime;
GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(out filetime);
var whatYoureLookingFor = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(filetime);
```

The giveaway is that the function returns a `long`. A `long` is an integer. It's never going to look like a `DateTime`.